# Is it a linear mass-spring system?

Tags: spring, vibrations, non-linear-systems, linear-systems

Please look at this equation representing a mass-spring system:

${\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}}+2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}+\omega _{0}^{\,2}x=F$

where the function of $F$ is unknown (i.e. it can possibly be $-2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}$ or $(-2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}})^2$).

So the question: MUST this mass-spring system be a *linear system*?

It may look simple, but I am really confused.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: So where exactly do you see a possible non-linearity?

Comment: Your possible values of $F(t)$ are wrong because as the notation suggests, $F$ is an explicit function of the time only.

Comment: The nonlinear terms brought from F(t), which can possibly include $x^2$ etc. So do u think F(t) is not possible to bring in non-linearity? i.e. F(t) can not possibly include terms like $x^2$.

Comment: @Peaceful thanks for flagging. I have changed the equation. It is unknown that F is an explicit function of only t or not, it may also contain other terms.

Comment: It is pretty standard (from differential equations theory) that $F$ in this case represents a non-homogeneous term that depends only on $t$. This is the equation of a driven damped oscillator and it is linear since it satisfies the superposition principle.

Comment: Which means that if you have any nonlinear term on the LHS, you can bring that to right and call it a part of $F$. This simply means that your equation can be linear or non-linear depending upon F.

Comment: @Diracology thanks. I actually made a mistake in the equation. I have corrected it now. F does not depend only on t.

Comment: @Peaceful thanks! So it also means the system can be a nonlinear mass-spring system?

Comment: Yes. But then you would rather not write it in this form.

Comment: @Peaceful thank you very much! I will keep on thinking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go from definition of linearity.

If $x$ and $y$ are solutions of differential equation defined by linear operator $H$, then $x+y$ is also solution.

In other words, if $Hx=0$ and $Hy=0$, then it should follow that $H(x+y)=0$

Another property of linear operators is scaling: $H(\alpha x)=\alpha H(x)$

In your case it is easy to see that operator defining equation is non-linear. Let's say that $x$ and $y$ are solutions to the equation. Let's assume that $(x+y)$ is also solution:

${\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}(x+y)}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}}+2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} (x+y)}{\mathrm {d} t}}+\omega _{0}^{\,2}(x+y)=(-2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} (x+y)}{\mathrm {d} t}})^2$

If you expand it:

${\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}}+{\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}y}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}} +
2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}+
2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} y}{\mathrm {d} t}}+
\omega _{0}^{\,2}x+
\omega _{0}^{\,2}y
=4(\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}})^2+
4(\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} y}{\mathrm {d} t}})^2+
8(\zeta \omega_{0})^2 {\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}{\frac {\mathrm {d} y}{\mathrm {d} t}}$

You will see requirement for $(x+y)$ to be solution:
$8(\zeta \omega_{0})^2 {\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}{\frac {\mathrm {d} y}{\mathrm {d} t}}=0$

Which is not automatically follows from $x$ and $y$ being solutions.

Hence, original operator (or original equation) is non-linear.

Comment: Thank u. So I guess that is the definition of linear system: f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) is true for any function x, y and any value of t.

Comment: that is very crude approximation, but easy to understand. In fact, linearity means two things: $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Here the question is what you consider as input and what you consider as system. If you consider F also part of the system, then it is not spring mass system anymore. But still any linear F will cause the system to be linear . Any system with and input can be non-linear if you rewrite with input as part of the system. A system had input and output.
In a nutshell, system is linear if F is input to the system. System is linear if you consider F as part of system and F is linear. System is non-linear when you consider F as part of system and F is nonlinear. (In cases where F is part of the system you cannot consider it the classic spring mass system) . You can use the superposition condition to verify this.Also one must also keep in mind that spring mass system is a classic linear reference model we use in control systems. Also any nonlinear system cannot be written as transfer functions.
Hope this gives an insight to your issue.